How to Determine the AES Mode Used for an Encrypted Binary File?
I'm working with a binary file that has been encrypted using the AES cipher, but I'm unsure of which mode of operation was used (e.g., ECB, CBC, GCM, etc.). I need to automate the process of identifying the mode, if possible. The binary file is encrypted, and I don't have the key and don't want to brute force the key.

If you only have the encrypted data then you can't get the cipher mode used. There are only some exceptions that allow you to guess a bit:

If you know the exact length of the pure encrypted data and it's length does not fit to the AES block size then there is a chance that a stream mode like GCM or CFB was used.

If the decrypted data has redundancies (is not compressed) and you see repeated patterns in the encrypted data then most likely ECB mode is used. See also the famous ECB encrypted Tux image at Wikipedia.

If the encrypted data is very large, GCM mode becomes unlikely, as most implementations process GCM mode in memory, especially when decrypting. In addition GCM mode has fixed maximum size of 64GB.


If you want to get the cipher mode used you have to decompile the program that encrypts/decrypts the data.
